# How to install Ubuntu Budgie over Ubuntu 16.04 (that already has Unity)

Tags: 16.04, unity, ubuntu-budgie

I have Ubuntu 16.04, and I would like to upgrade it to the new [Ubuntu 18 Budgie](https://ubuntubudgie.org/)

In order to do that, should I first upgrade Ubuntu to 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver and then install the [Budgie Desktop](https://github.com/budgie-desktop/budgie-desktop)?

**Is that the same as installing Ubuntu Budgie from scratch?**

How can I do that when I already have Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity? How may I uninstall unity and use Budgie instead?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your steps will look like:

1. Upgrade to 18.04 LTS
2. Install [Ubuntu Budgie Desktop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu-budgie-desktop) package with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-budgie-desktop
   ```

Then you can decide to remove or save Unity session from the system. The difference from clean installation of Budgie is that you will have 3 sessions in the system - Unity, GNOME and Budgie. Removing Unity-related packages is not too easy task.

Comment: Isn't a fresh install better for OP?

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, but what's OP?

Comment: George asks you (OP - original poster) and me about doing clean installation. Because of "Removing Unity-related packages is not too easy task." I think.

Comment: Oh I see! Well, yes, I'm actually thinking about doing a clean install instead :)

Comment: After installing Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 from scratch (before I was using 16.04 with Unity) I had to uninstall the nvidia drivers with: `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia-*`; Otherwise the budgie desktop was not starting.